# How to format integer with spaces in Django templates

Tags: python, django-templates, string-formatting

I have to format integers with spaces in a Django template in this way:

```
0 -> 000 0000
1 -> 000 0001
2 -> 000 0002
...
10000 -> 001 0000
10001 -> 001 0001
...
9999998 -> 999 9998
9999999 -> 999 9999
```

How do I format the integers in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This `templatetag` can solve the problem:

```
def spaced_format(value):
    left = int(value / 10000)
    right = value % 10000
    return '{:03} {:04}'.format(left, right)
```

In template:

```
{% load my_template_tag_module %}

{{ my_integer|spaced_format }}
```

More information about Django custom template tags is available at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/